# For a field $\theta \equiv \theta(t,x,y)$, is $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}$ for independent $x$,$y$,$t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

Consider a field $\theta$ defined over its independent variables $x$, $y$ and $t$.
$$\theta \equiv \theta(t,x,y) \tag{1}$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $t$,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}  +  \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}  +   \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} \tag{2}$$

My colleague said that $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}$ because $x$ and $y$ are independent of $t$.

I wasn't too sure about that and gave the example that if we have a temperature field $\theta(t,x,y)$ defined over a two dimensional plane, equation (2) holds good but it doesn't mean anything till we define a trajectory through the plane parametrized by $x \equiv x(t)$ and $y \equiv y(t)$. Then $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$ take finite values and you can calculate an analytical expression for $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}$. My colleague said my intuition was coming from particle mechanics (which he is right about) but for a field $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}$. However, I still think that to say $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}$ is like defining a trajectory where you are standing at a fixed point ($x$,$y$) and evaluating $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}$ there. In this case, I would agree with him. However, if $x$ and $y$ are independent of $t$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ should be undefined and can't be zero because for a small change in $t$, the corresponding change in $x$ could be anything since $x$ and $t$ are independent of each other.

Can someone please shed some light on my issue regarding how do I make physical sense of $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}$ when $x$ and $y$ are independent of $t$.

Comment: Take it back to definitions. What is $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ supposed to mean as distinct from $\frac{\partial theta}{\partial t}$ in this context? If you can't name a distinction, then just stick with one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with notation and abuse of language. First of all $\theta$ is a function of 3 variables, so writing $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ is just wrong. Yes, people write it all the time, but it is wrong. The two $\theta$'s mean completely different things on the two sides of the equation.

The chain rule tells us the following. Suppose we have a (differentiable) parametrized curve $\gamma:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$. Then, we can construct a **NEW** function $\Theta:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ as $\Theta(t)=\theta(t,\gamma(t))=\theta(t,\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$. It may probably be a good idea to write $\Theta_{\gamma}$ to emphasize that this function is constructed from $\theta$ and the curve $\gamma$... but I won't simply for ease of typing. Then,
\begin{align}
\Theta'(t)&=(\partial_1\theta)_{(t,\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))}\cdot 1 +
(\partial_2\theta)_{(t,\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))}\cdot \gamma_1'(t)+
(\partial_3\theta)_{(t,\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))}\cdot \gamma_2'(t)\tag{i}
\end{align}
Or, written in slightly more classical notation,
\begin{align}
\frac{d\Theta}{dt}\bigg|_t&=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}\bigg|_{(t,\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))}+
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(t,\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))}\cdot
\frac{d\gamma_1}{dt}\bigg|_t+
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(t,\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))}\cdot
\frac{d\gamma_2}{dt}\bigg|_t\tag{ii}
\end{align}
Or if you go one step further and omit the points of evaluation (which are actually important, since this equation expresses what happens only along the curve $\gamma$), we can write
\begin{align}
\frac{d\Theta}{dt}&=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}+
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\frac{d\gamma_1}{d t}+
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}\frac{d\gamma_2}{d t}\tag{iii}
\end{align}
The sloppiest of all is
\begin{align}
\frac{d\theta}{dt}&=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}+
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{d t}+
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{d t},\tag{iv}
\end{align}
because the $\theta$ on the LHS really should be $\Theta$ which is a **completely different function**, and the symbol $x$ has two meanings. One is an arbitrary placeholder for the second entry of the function $\theta$, and also as the first component of the parametrized curve. Similarly, $y$ has two meanings. ALso, the points of evaluation are not indicated at all.

If you're still not convinced of the dangers of such condensed notation/ are unfamiliar with it, perhaps [Partial Derivatives of Functions of Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3270436/568204) might help.

---

Getting directly to the case you're asking about, let us fix a point $(a,b)\in\Bbb{R}^2$, and suppose we consider the constant curve $\gamma:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$, defined as $\gamma(t)=(a,b)$. Now, if you plug this into equations (i) or (ii), you'll see that the function $\Theta$ is defined as $\Theta(t):=\theta(t,\gamma(t))=\theta(t,a,b)$, and that its derivative is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{d\Theta}{dt}\bigg|_t&=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}\bigg|_{(t,a,b)}+0+0.
\end{align}
Well, this should be obvious even from the very definition of a partial derivative. The meaning of the partial derivative symbol $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}\bigg|_{(t,a,b)}$ or $(\partial_1\theta)_{(t,a,b)}$ means we fix all the other entries, so that we're left with a single-variable function  $\Theta(\cdot)=\theta(\cdot, a,b)$, and then calculate the derivative of this function at $t$. This is literally definition. There's no need to talk about fields/particle motion or anything else.

Note however, that you should not fall into the trap of saying $\frac{d\Theta}{dt}=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}$. On the LHS, $\Theta:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is a function of one variable, so its derivative $\Theta'=\frac{d\Theta}{dt}:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is also a function of one variable. On the RHS, $\theta:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$ is a function of 3 variables, hence its partial derivative $\partial_1\theta=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$
is also a function of 3 variables. A function of one-variable can never be equal to a function of three variables.

So, you adivsor's claim that $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}$ (or even with my slightly more precise notation, the "equation" $\frac{d\Theta}{dt}=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}$) are strictly speaking wrong. They are only equal if you know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You should forget about the case when $x$ and $y$ depend on $t$ (which is a more complicated case) and just come back to the definition of partial derivatives: $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}$ means exactly that you fix $x$ and $y$ and take the derivative of $\theta$ with respect to $t$.

Your confusion comes from the fact that in physics, notations are ambiguous in that you don't clearly distinguish between the case where $x$ and $y$ are **variables**, and when they are **functions** (of t in this case). In the setting you are asking about, $x$ and $y$ are variables, and the expressions $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$ are not meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct. The symbol $d\theta/dt$ only has definite sense whenever we have chosen a class of curves passing through each point of the plane $x, y$. Then, that derivative is understood as the derivative of $\theta$ along the curves (and is calculated by the chain rule).

However, in field theory, the class of curves is usually implicitly inderstood to be the motion of particles *subject to the field* $\theta$. This means that, related to the field $\theta$, there's a system of differential equations of motion.

The formula $d\theta/dt= \partial\theta/\partial t$ can then be deduced from those differential equations.

For example, if $\theta$ was the energy function and $x, y$ were canonical coordinates of phase space, then the equations would be:

$$dx/dt= \partial \theta/\partial y$$

$$dy/dt= -\partial \theta/\partial x$$

And then the chain rule would imply that $d\theta/dt= \partial \theta/\partial t$.

But, since your advisor says that $x$ and $y$ are constant with $t$, then it must be what other answer says, and those curves are constant.

Answer (score 0):

In my "early" time I could solve the dilemma (which in Thermodynamics become even more intricated)
by keeping firm the pivot of the total differential
$$
d\theta  = \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial x}}dx + \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial y}}dy +
 \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial z}}dz +  \cdots \quad \left| {\,x,y,z\;{\rm independent}} \right.
$$

Then it follows that:

- if $\theta$ does not depend on $z$, or if $z$ is a constant (held constant) and not a variable
  $$
  d\theta \left( {x,y} \right) = d\theta \left( {x,y,z = c} \right) = \left. {d\theta \left( {x,y,z} \right)} \right|_{\,z = c}
    = \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial x}}dx + \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial y}}dy + 0dz
  $$
- if $z$ actually depends on $x,y$
  $$
  \begin{array}{l}
   d\theta \left( {x,y,z(x,y)} \right) = \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial x}}dx + \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial y}}dy +
   \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial z}}\left( {dz} \right) =  \\ 
    = \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial x}}dx + \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial y}}dy + \frac{{\partial \theta }}
  {{\partial z}}\left( {\frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial x}}dx + \frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial y}}dy} \right) =  \\ 
    = \left( {\frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial x}} + \frac{{\partial \theta }}
  {{\partial z}}\frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial x}}} \right)dx + \left( {\frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial y}} +
   \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial z}}\frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial y}}} \right)dy \\ 
   \end{array}
  $$
- if $x,y, \ldots$ actually depend on a further variable $t$
  $$
  \begin{array}{l}
   d\theta \left( {x(t),y(t), \cdots } \right)
   = \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial x}}\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}dt + \frac{{\partial \theta }}
  {{\partial y}}\frac{{dy}}{{dt}}dt +  \cdots  =  \\ 
    = \left( {\frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial x}}\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}
   + \frac{{\partial \theta }}{{\partial y}}\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} +  \cdots } \right)dt
   = \frac{{d\theta }}{{dt}}dt \\ 
   \end{array}
  $$
- if $\cdots$