# Partial Derivative Chain Rule When Variables Are Not Independent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let's say, $x$ is a function of $t$ ($x = x(t)$) and $y$ is a function of $t$ ($y = y(t)$). And, $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ ($f = f(x, y)$). Then by the chain rule $$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$. However, when you take the partial derivative of a function wrt a variable you keep all other variables constant. So, I am not sure how $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ above can be calculated, since you cannot keep $y$ constant if $x$ is allowed to be varied and vice-versa. Can someone please explain what I am understanding wrong?

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is calculated for $x$ independent variable and then it can be considered at point $(x(t), y(t))$.

Comment: $f(x,y)$ is a mapping from $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^1$, and its partial derivatives are computed independently of any other mappings, which in your case is $\mathbb R^1 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ and defined by functions $x(t),y(t)$.

Comment: To be clear, the chain rule generally is applied when the variables *are* mutually dependent on one another.

Comment: I suggest you read [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4384452/568204) and the various link in there. The issue is you need to be crystal clear on what the notation means and what it doesn't mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are using $x$ as both as a free variable, and as a function, $x(t)$. And likewise $y$.

---

The notation $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is really being used as an *implicit* shorthand for $\dfrac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial t}$.

$~$ Where $f(x(t),y(t))$ is a convolution of the bivariate function $f$, with monovariate functions $x$ and $y$, each evaluated with the same argument $t$, a free variable.

---

Likewise you are using the notation $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is used as shorthand for $\left.\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\right\vert_{\raise{2ex}{u:=x(t)\\v:=y(t)}}$ .

$~$ That means to evaluate the partial differential of $f$ with respect to its first argument and *then* form a composition by substituting those arguments with $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

$~$ Thus you are evaluating the partial differential of the field $f(u,v)$ over the $t$ parametised curve $\{\langle x(t),y(t)\rangle\}$

---

So the chain rule is actually:

$$\dfrac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial t}=\left.\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\right\vert_{\raise{2ex}{u:=x(t)\\v:=y(t)}}\cdotp\dfrac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}+\left.\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}\right\vert_{\raise{2ex}{u:=x(t)\\v:=y(t)}}\cdotp\dfrac{\partial y(t)}{\partial t}$$

But this is annoying to read and write, so the shorthand is used for convenience.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!